# Is it possible to create a command with another command, passing code as a string?

Tags: macros, foreach, makecell

I want to loop through a list and print some text.  The placement of that text is inside a table, inside a \makecell command.  I could hard-code the items from the list I want, including some \\ commands to break lines.  But I don't want to hard-code, I want to use a loop.  MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\AuthorList{First MI. Last, First MI. Last, First MI. Last}
\newcommand\PrintAuthorList{\foreach \x in \AuthorList
    {
        \x
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I want to print the author list, one per line:\\ \PrintAuthorList}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I've hard-coded the result I want:\\ First MI. Last\\First MI. Last\\First MI. Last}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

That code will compile but will not break lines between author names.  If I add \\ to the foreach loop, it won't even compile.

My thought is that I have one command create a string with the slashes that I want, and have that string passed as code in my \makecell environment.  For example:

```
\newcommand{\MakeAuthorString}{\foreach \x in \AuthorList{\x\textbackslash\textbackslash}}
```

But passing this into the makecell environment obviously just prints the backslashes as text.  I want the string to be passed somehow as code... with actual backslashes that don't evaluate until they get in the makecell environment.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\begin{table*}[h]` : `table*` is for tables that span two columns and does not have `h` it just does something here as in single node `table*` drops back to being `table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one liner with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\AuthorList{First MI. Last, First MI. Last, First MI. Last}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\PrintAuthorList{}
 {
  \clist_use:Nn \AuthorList { \\ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
\hline
row 2, no cells & \makecell{Author List:\\ \PrintAuthorList}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you like `\expandafter`-orgies, you can use `\foreach` for accumulating table-rows in a temporary macro:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\AuthorList{First MI. Last1, First MI. Last2, First MI. Last3}
\newcommand\MyTemp{}%
\newcommand\PrintAuthorList{%
  \gdef\MyTemp{}%
  \foreach \x in \AuthorList
  {%
    \ifx\MyTemp\empty\else
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\MyTemp\expandafter{\MyTemp\\}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MyTemp
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\MyTemp
    \x}%
  }%
  %\show\MyTemp
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\MyTemp\expandafter{\expandafter}\MyTemp
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I want to print the author list, one per line:\\ \PrintAuthorList}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I've hard-coded the result I want:\\ First MI. Last1\\First MI. Last2\\First MI. Last3}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A variant without `pgffor` and without temporary macro—the author-names in `\AuthorList` must contain neither unbalanced `\else`/`\fi` nor tokens whose meaning equals the meaning of `\MyListEndDenoter` :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcommand\AuthorList{% 
  % Not a comma-list this time but a list of undelimited/brace-nested arguments:
  {First MI. Last1}%
  {First MI. Last2}%
  {First MI. Last3}%
}%

\newcommand\PrintAuthorList{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\AuthorList}{\AccumulateTableRowsLoop{}{}}{\MyListEndDenoter}%
}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AccumulateTableRowsLoop[3]{%
  % #1 - Either empty or \\
  % #2 - Accumulated table rows
  % #3 - Element of AuthorList or \MyListEndDenoter
  \ifx\MyListEndDenoter#3\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {#2}{\AccumulateTableRowsLoop{\\}{#2#1#3}}%
}%
\makeatother
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\MyListEndDenoter{ItMustHaveAWeirdAndBizarreDefinitionWhichNoOtherMacroHas}%


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I want to print the author list, one per line:\\ \PrintAuthorList}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \makecell[tl]{row 1, line 1 \\ row 1, row 2} & stuff\\
        \hline
        row 2, no cells & \makecell{This is where I've hard-coded the result I want:\\ First MI. Last1\\First MI. Last2\\First MI. Last3}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]